# How to validate size of files while uploading on ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation, upload

I'm developing a module to send emails, and one of the features is to upload multiple files...

I used this as a reference to create it:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=68

I also had to add jquery to allow it to upload multiple files.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery.MultiFile.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

However, if I upload a file that is larger than 10MB when I press a button in my form (I guess it happens whenever a postback occurs), the browser cannot load the page. So what I want is to trigger this function in my button:

```
protected void imgBtnEnviar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int intBytes = 0;
    string strArchivos = "";
    string strRutaArchivos = "";
    bool blnBytes = true;
    bool blnPermitir = true;

    try
    {
        HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;

        //Check if all files together are less than 10mb
        foreach (HttpPostedFile hpf in hfc)
        {
            intBytes += hpf.ContentLength;

            if (intBytes > 11000000)
            {
                blnBytes = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (blnBytes)
        {
            //Upload All attached files to server
            foreach (HttpPostedFile hpf in hfc)
            {
                if (hpf.FileName == "")
                {
                    break;
                }

                string strNombre = ((int)Session["Grupo"]) + "_" + (int)Session["EmailIdCliente"] + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH.mm.ss") + "_" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                strArchivos += strNombre + ";";
                strRutaArchivos += Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/") + strNombre + ";";
                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/") + strNombre);
            }
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        blnPermitir = false;
    }

    if (!blnBytes || !blnPermitir)
    {
        //Error Message Displayed To User
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Mensaje", "alert('Maximo Puede Enviar 10MB En Archivos');", true);
    }

    else
    {
        //Moving on to send email
    }
}
```

What I want is that if blnBytes equals false (it becomes false when all combined files are more than 10mb) it just displays an error message, but how can I make it work even if a single file is larger than 10mb??....

Hope you can help me with that
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable large file support in web.config (httpRuntime, maxRequestLength parameter).

Here is sample:

```
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"
     executionTimeout="6000"
     maxRequestLength="20485760"
     requestLengthDiskThreshold="80"
     useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
     minFreeThreads="8"
     minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
     appRequestQueueLimit="5000"
     enableKernelOutputCache="true"
     enableVersionHeader="true"
     requireRootedSaveAsPath="true"
     enable="true"
     shutdownTimeout="90"
     delayNotificationTimeout="5"
     waitChangeNotification="0"
     maxWaitChangeNotification="0"
     enableHeaderChecking="true"
     sendCacheControlHeader="true"
     apartmentThreading="false" />
```

More about this can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You may try this..

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile hpf in hfc)
{
    if(hpf.ContentLength > 11000000)
    {
        blnBytes = false;
        break;
    }
    intBytes += hpf.ContentLength;
    if (intBytes > 11000000)
    {
        blnBytes = false;
        break;
    }
}
```